# Can I add a 60 amp hot tub on a 100 amp service?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I'm adding a hot tub to our backyard. The hot tub can pull up to a max of 60 amps when all the pumps and heater are going. However, a sales rep said it's not common that you would be pulling all 60 amps at once. The problem is that we only have 100 amp service. The place we are buying the hot tub from recommended 2 electricians. One didn't seem too thrilled about having to potentially upgrade to 100 amp, so he never sent a quote over and ignored our calls. The other said 100 amp service would be fine. Our house isn't particularly large, just 1500 sqft. He said for our size house we're probably only pulling about 20-30 amps now and wouldn't invest in upgrading to 200 as it can be pricey and unnecessary. We do have gas and that is used by our water heater, stove, and furnace.

Would a 100 amp service cut it?

The electrician did say that we don't have any room left in the panel so a new sub panel would need to be installed to the right. He said that would be cheaper than installing an entire new one.

Link to album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy9bD.jpg

Comment: Can you post photos of your breaker panel please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, yep! Just added an album.

Comment: Yeah, you’ve got an all electric house (except water heater??) crammed onto a 100A service.  It can just handle what you got now, but no more.

Comment: @Eric -- how many kW is your oven/range (and is it just an oven, or a full range), how many amps does your A/C pull, and how many circuits do you have feeding your kitchen countertop receptacles?

Comment: I would install a 200 amp service to be safe. Your service is too small for what you are trying to add.

Comment: Is there an electric oven? Just a receptacle I would want to take a power measurement before adding a sub , I would say if you actually have an electric oven you would need to upgrade your service. There are ways to do this that meet the latest code also, install a 200 amp load center outside at the meter feed your existing main panel from the new outside unit then feed the hot tub from that new service. This would provide external disconnects a new 2020 code requirement, and provide enough ampacity to not have to worry about load shedding while all the pumps on the tub are on.

Comment: Your A/C and clothes dryer will use 50A.  Add the hot tub (which probably uses 50A) and you're at 100% already, without the well, microwave, pool pump, wash machine...If you have to think about what is on when you want to use the hot tub then it is too small.